# Get the latest record within a date range in one table based on the dates in another

Tags: sql, join, oracle10g, left-join

I have the following tables in an Oracle 10 database.

TABLE_A that lists IDs and an associated date:

```
ID         DATE
-----------------------
A1234    | 31-Dec-2008 
B5678    | 31-Dec-2009
A1234    | 31-Dec-2010
```

TABLE_B that gives ratings for the IDs at month ends:

```
ID         RATING_DATE   RATING
--------------------------------
A1234    | 31-Dec-2008 | 3
A1234    | 31-Jan-2009 | 3
A1234    | 28-Feb-2009 | 3
A1234    | 31-Mar-2009 | 2
A1234    | 30-Apr-2009 | 2
A1234    | 31-May-2009 | 3
A1234    | 31-Jun-2009 | 2
A1234    | 31-Jan-2010 | 3
A1234    | 28-Feb-2010 | 3
B5678    | 31-Dec-2009 | 4
B5678    | 31-Dec-2010 | 4
B5678    | 31-Jan-2011 | 4
B5678    | 28-Feb-2011 | 4
```

**What I need:**

For all the `ID`, `DATE` pairs in TABLE_A, I want to find the latest `RATING_DATE` and `RATING` in TABLE_B within the range [DATE, DATE + 12 months).

**eg:** For `A1234    | 31-Dec-2008`, I would be interested in finding the latest `RATING_DATE` and `RATING` within 31 Dec 2008 - 30 Nov 2009. Here, I would want `A1234    | 31-Jun-2009 | 2`

I have the following SQL to get the latest `RATING_DATE`, but I can't figure out how to get the `RATING` as well:

```
SELECT      A.DATE, 
            A.ID, 
            MAX(TABLE_B.RATING_DATE)

FROM        TABLE_A A LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B
            ON
            A.ID = B.ID
            AND
            B.RATING_DATE >= A.DATE
            AND
            B.RATING_DATE < ADD_MONTHS(A.DATE, 12)

GROUP BY    A.DATE, 
            A.ID
```

Is there some way of getting this done without nested joins or other sub-queries?

Comment: **SQL** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems - not a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: Why `31 Dec 2008 - 30 Nov 2009` and not `31 Dec 2008 - 30 Dec 2009`?  YOu may also like to know that most implementations of SQL allow sub-queries `SELECT * FROM (your query here) AS sub_query INNER JOIN another_table ON sub_query.x = another_table.y`

Comment: @marc_s: My bad - I missed that. It's Oracle 10 and I've edited the question to include it. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Dems: The date range is just part of the requirements. I was hoping to see if there was some wway of doing this with just a single left join and no other subqueries or joins

Comment: @FBNMDN - Why no sub-queries?  That's a deliberate part of the SQL language.  Oracle 10 has a perfectly good optimiser to compile them into good plans.

Comment: @Dems: If that is the case, I wouldn't mind going ahead with a sub-query. But do you think a sub-query is more efficient or another join is more efficient like moleboy points out below?

Comment: @FBNMDN - Ummm, MoleBoy *is* using a sub-query... `SELECT ... FROM (sub-query) AS v1 LEFT JOIN ...`  I would either use that, or use ROW_NUMBER() to accomplish something very similar.

Comment: Are the dates in `table_a` always the _first_ entry in `table_b`?  What should happen if there are gaps (if anything)?  Should you worry about ids in `table_a` that have dates in `table_b` _before_ the date in `table_a`?  Is there a specific reason you're only doing the range of one year, or is it because of the progression of dates in `table_a`?

Comment: @X-Zero:
If there are gaps I expect `NULL` to be returned for `RATING_DATE` and `RATING`

No worries about dates in table_b that appear before the date in table_a.

The reason for the range of one year is purely because of the requirements in hand.

Comment: _any_ gaps?  That's going to complicate the query  - if you think it takes a while now... or did you just mean 'none avaliable'?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that meets the specified requirements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
     , a.date_
     , LAST_VALUE(b.rating_date) OVER (PARTITION BY a.id, a.date_ ORDER BY b.rating_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_rating_date
     , LAST_VALUE(b.rating)      OVER (PARTITION BY a.id, a.date_ ORDER BY b.rating_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_rating 
  FROM table_a a
  LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.id 
       AND b.rating_date >= a.date_ AND b.rating_date < ADD_MONTHS(a.date_,12)
 ORDER BY a.id, a.date_
```

And here's another option:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
     , a.date_
     , MAX(b.rating_date) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY b.rating_date) OVER(PARTITION BY a.id, a.date_) as last_rating_date 
     , MAX(b.rating     ) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY b.rating_date) OVER(PARTITION BY a.id, a.date_) as last_rating
  FROM table_a a
  LEFT 
  JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.id AND b.rating_date >= a.date_ AND b.rating_date < ADD_MONTHS(a.date_,12)
 ORDER BY a.id, a.date_
```

---

both return the same resultset:

```
ID    DATE_      LAST_RATING_DATE LAST_RATING
----- ---------- ---------------- -----------
A1234 2008-12-31 2009-06-30                 2
A1234 2010-12-31                             
B5678 2009-12-31 2009-12-31                 4
```

NOTE: to setup a test environment, I changed the name of the `date` column in `table_a` to be `date_`.

```
create table table_a (id varchar2(5), date_ date);
create table table_b (id varchar2(5), rating_date date, rating int);
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
insert into table_a values ('A1234','2008-12-31');
insert into table_a values ('B5678','2009-12-31');
insert into table_a values ('A1234','2010-12-31');
insert into table_b values ('A1234','2008-12-31',3);
insert into table_b values ('A1234','2009-01-31',3);
insert into table_b values ('A1234','2009-02-28',3);
insert into table_b values ('A1234','2009-03-31',2);
insert into table_b values ('A1234','2009-04-30',2);
insert into table_b values ('A1234','2009-05-31',3);
insert into table_b values ('A1234','2009-06-30',2);
insert into table_b values ('A1234','2010-01-31',3);
insert into table_b values ('A1234','2010-02-28',3);
insert into table_b values ('B5678','2009-12-31',4);
insert into table_b values ('B5678','2010-12-31',4);
insert into table_b values ('B5678','2011-01-31',4);
insert into table_b values ('B5678','2011-02-28',4);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I love analytics, but I'm still forcing my brain to think in those terms.  This is a great example to learn from.

Comment: @moleboy: The analytics don't come naturally to me either. If I needed this result set, I would use a query similar to the one in your answer.  The original question asked how to get this result set "without nested joins or sub-queries". Personally, I don't see a need to avoid joins or sub-queries.  They are powerful and are often the most efficient way to retrieve a particular resultset. The fix for poor performance of joins and correlated sub-queries is to add the appropriate indexes.

Comment: I'm with you on the indexes (obviously), though I am finding those to be not an option much of the time at my current position.  The client keeps a really tight grip on everything, so adding indexes can be a real hassle.  We've gotten around it sometimes by creating something of a mirror, but that can be a pain in and of itself.

Comment: "creating something of a mirror" :) -- Our funding for mirrors has been cut, we now rely solely on smoke.

Comment: YOU GET SMOKE?  Jeez, someone's gonna get OSHA sicced on them!

Comment: You guys must get away with EVERYTHING...(smoke AND mirrors...some jobs just spoil their database people...)

Answer (score 0):

While the particular implementation of SQL might make this easier, I think this should work for you

```
SELECT v1.id, v1.myDate, v1.rating_date, b2.rating
FROM (SELECT a.id, a.myDate, MAX(b.rating_date) rating_date
      FROM tab_a a 
      LEFT JOIN tab_b b
      ON a.id = b.id
      AND b.rating_date >= a.myDate
      AND b.rating_date < ADD_MONTHS(a.myDate, 12)
      GROUP BY a.id, a.myDate) v1
LEFT JOIN tab_b b2
ON v1.id = b2.id
AND v1.rating_date = b2.rating_date
```

Comment: I'm sure this works. But I was actually looking to avoid multiple joins and sub-queries.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to avoid multiple joins.  If you are looking to avoid those, you should stop with databases right now ;)
However, you might try looking at Oracle Analytics.  I don't think they'll make you any happier, though.

Comment: Haha. It's not that I don't like multiple joins. 

TABLE_B has ~38M records - I just tried running the multiple join and it took ~5 mins.

Comment: Might I suggest an index?  ;)

Comment: @moleboy: you might actually suggest two indexes: `create index table_a_ix1 on table_a (id, date_, ADD_MONTHS(date_,12));` and 
`create index table_b_ix1 ON table_b (id, rating_date, rating);`

Answer (score 0):

```
MAX(B.RATING) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY RATING_DATE)
```

This assumes that you want the largest rating if there are multiple ratings in the last month.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions065.htm#i1000901) is the documentation for `FIRST` and `LAST` syntax.  (By the way, June 31 does not exist.)